# How to automatically run the python script when a new csv file appears

Tags: python, csv, automation

I need a solution so that a ready python script will run every time a new csv file appears in the folder. The script uses this csv file, which will always have the same name, but it will be updated from time to time and then the script should run automatically.
I am not an advanced python user, so I can't handle it myself and the solution will make my work much easier. I am asking for tips on how to do it or send some tutorial or code.
Have a nice day everyone :)

Comment: You can use something like Watchdog for this https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. It offers no information at all. All SO questions are about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `program` or `code`